# error: 'int main(int, char**)' previously defined here in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, program-entry-point, redefinition, googletest

I'm implementing gtest now, and it gives me an error : main previously defined here.

Here's utest.cpp

```
// Bring in my package's API, which is what I'm testing
#include "../src/test.cpp"
// Bring in gtest
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

// Declare a test
TEST(TestSuite, testCase1)
{
     EXPECT_EQ(5,getX(5));
}

// Run all the tests that were declared with TEST()
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And here's the code that i'm testing
test.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <Project2Sample/R_ID.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>


#include <sstream>
#include "math.h"

int getX(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

There's nothing in test.cpp main but actual code will have some codes in main.

I dont have header files for utest and test cpp files

I tried

```
#ifndef UTEST_H
#define UTEST_H
```

and didn't solve the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message states what the problem is, you have two `main()` functions. I believe you want to remove the duplicate `main()` from test.cpp.

Comment: It works! thank you :) will accept your answer after 5 min! :)